# How to give reference to static resources like css,images,java script in JSP?

Tags: java, css, jsp

How to give reference to Static resources like `CSS, images, Java Script` in JSP?
My Web- Application structure is like this:

```
Web Pages
|     ↓
|    Pages
|     ↳  index.jsp <--uses style1.css
↳    Resources
      ↳  css
          ↳  style1.css
```

Inside index.jsp:

```
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Resources/css/style1.css" />
 </head>
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What `doctype` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Resources/css/style1.css" />
 </head>
```

Comment: Can you explain meaning of `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`?

Comment: @M.S. This gives you the contextpath where your application is deployed.